# Android canvas.drawBitmap very slow with ARGB_8888

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, draw

I am new in Android coding, but I'd like to make an app for tablets with a pen to be able to handwrite (I know there are already plenty out there but I want my own one)

I collected some code from all over the Internet and now I am at the point that I'd like to add an eraser mode. For that, I am creating a Bitmap which is then added on a Canvas.
It all works fine, but the Bitmap has the `Bitmap.Configuration.ARGB_8888` and that is slow when drawing, so it lags behind. I tried `Bitmap.Configuration.RGB_565` and had no performance issues, but other problems with erasing.

I also found out, that it obviously has to do with the size of the Bitmap. My tablet has a screen resolution of 1920x1200. When I am creating the Bitmap with only `1557x1000` I have no performance problems, but as I increase it to `1558x1000` or higher it starts to lag again.

Here is a part of my code:

**class DrawView:**

```
public class DrawView extends SurfaceView implements View.OnTouchListener{
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint bitmapPaint;
    private Path path;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    private int currentColor;
    private float currentStrokeWidth;
    private boolean eraserMode = false;

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

        path = new Path();
        paint = new Paint();
        bitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(false);
        // ... setting Color and StorkeWidth to paint
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
        c.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
        c.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(eventX, eventY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(eventX, eventY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            invalidate();
       }
       return true;
    }

    private float mX, mY;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        path.reset();
    }
}
```

I am very glad if someone could help me fixing this issue.

Comment: canvas is slow when using transparency like ARGB_8888 use RGB_565 reason being in ARGB_8888 Each pixel is stored on 4 bytes and RGB + alpha channel is encoded whereas in RGB_565
Each pixel is stored on 2 bytes and only the RGB channels are encoded: red is stored with 5 bits of precision (32 possible values), green is stored with 6 bits of precision (64 possible values) and blue is stored with 5 bits of precision. of course there will be a little quality issue.

Comment: why do you draw the path **twice**? you do in `touch_move()` (respectively in `touch_up`) and do it again in `onDraw()`... i would purge the drawPath in `onDraw()`

Comment: @MartinFrank thanks, I didn't see that :)
@Bali the problem with RGB_565 is erasing. As I don't have a background with one single color, I need transparent color with `paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by myself.
I realized that my background image I was setting with `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background)` had a too high resolution, I lowered it and now it works. I don't know why this affects drawing performance but that explains why I haven't found any answer on the internet